# IOS13: UIActivityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler not called after select save photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

`UIActivityViewController.completionwithitemshandler` not called after select "**save photo"** in `IOS13`.

My code is very simple:

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
        let result: [String: Any] = [
            "completed": NSNumber(value: completed),
            "app": activityType?.rawValue ?? ""
        ];
    }
```

It was only called the first time I save photo, but
I need to know the result everytime after click "save photo" in the popup, but the handler was not called.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check whether the UIActivityController deallocated or not first?